# How can I use regex to select multiple lines and end the string after a character is found?

Tags: regex, multiline

[image: Example of bullet points in Ulysses app]

I'm trying to use a regex that recognizes multiple lines of text and stops when a certain character is found, in this case the # character. I used

```
##[a-zA-Z][\s\S]*?(?=\n.*?)
```

but I don't quite understand what to add to the regex to make it find multiple lines that follow a specific list pattern (* or ##)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the test string in regex101.com

## Sample Text

```
## SECTIONS

  * [Congress]
  * [White House]
  * [Magazine]
  * [The Agenda]
  * [Video]
  * [Podcasts]

## 2020 Elections
```

The expected output is everything from the first ## to the last ##. I want the returned result to include this. Sorry forgot to update the regex.

[image: regex for multiple lines, as tested on regex101.com]

Comment: What is wrong with your current regex?  It might be correct already, at least for certain texts.

Comment: I'll show you from regex101.com

Comment: @Jon, you can also avoid posting images and just give us the links. This is teh case for regex101, where you can save and share the regex. It is probably available if you click on the three line on the top right of your screen.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/0WDw7f/1

Comment: Your sample text doesn't even have `foo` and it is not clear what should be matched in sample text

Comment: You provided the sample text, but where's the expected output?

Comment: Try this regex `##[\s\S]*?(?=##)`

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to include that last line?

Comment: use: `##[\s\S]*?(?=##|\z)` to get both matches